# How do I import a non relative path properly in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, error-handling, ecmascript-6

I'm having issues importing into my typescript class.

```
// Error thrown here...
import * as Foundation from 'foundation/foundation';

// This works fine, until I add the above import...
export class HelloWorldScene {
  constructor() {
    console.log("...success...");
  }
}
```

Whenever I try building my project using ts-loader to transpile it for me in a gulp webpack task, this error gets thrown:

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^
 Error: [object Object]
```

I'm Almost Certain it's because of how I'm importing the library.

Comment: have you set a baseUrl?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late,  but it may be useful in the future for someone..

Solution :

In this small example we use reactjs typescript webpack2, but using non-relative path

Configure compiler indicating base url and paths to resolve imports, by example : tsconfig.json in root directory p

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "src", // URL FIX 'src/comp1' TO  @import 'comp1'
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*", //Paths 
        "modules/*"
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

In webpack we specify the resolvers [webpack2 config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
        '.tsx',
        '.ts',
        '.json',
        '.js',
        '.jsx',
        '.css'
    ],
    modules: ["node_modules", 'src']

}
```

[full example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LM5e.png)

Result :

DIff between relative import and non-relative [typescript info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

I hope it helps someone

[image]